# Opening hamburger menu resets scroll on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have recently added a mobile hamburger menu to my website. However my website mainly consists and is built around one page. When I open the menu, no matter where you scroll in the page it brings you to the top. Also this seems to happen at the beginning of opening the menu as well as when closing the menu. I can tell because I notice the screen scrolling when clicking the ID links, but as one exits the menu the page's scroll goes back to the top. I believe the issue has to do with the JavaScript code I used. I've messed around with it, but I can't find the problem. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/47dtoc6c/1/

```
/* For Overlay on Menu */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button a").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
       $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });
});
$('.overlay').on('click', function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
    $(".button a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    open = false;
});
```

Above is the Jquery script for the menu overlay.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your menu button to a div and stick an id on it (this will remove the jump), then in your javascript add a click to close

e.g.

```
<div id="nav2">
  <div class="button">
    <div id=menu class="btn-open" ></div>
</div>



$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#menu").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });
```

});

css

```
#menu { cursor: pointer; }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you, I upvoted but I'm to new for it to show.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the event in your onClick function and set it to preventDefault()

```
$(".button a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        ....
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/47dtoc6c/2/